# Comstum magento extention doesnt save form post value

Tags: database, forms, magento, module

I'm trying to create a custom magento extension.

It works, only 1 form field is not saved to the db.

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('foo_bar/baz');
        $model->setData($postData);

        try {
            $model->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The baz has been saved.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        }   
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving this baz.'));
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBazData($postData);
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

The form:

```
  protected function _prepareForm()
{  
    $model = Mage::registry('foo_bar');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method'    => 'post'
    ));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend'    => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Baz Information'),
        'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'id',
        ));
    }  

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'name',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
        'required'  => true,
    ));

     $fieldset->addField('stock', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'stock',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('stock'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('stock'),
        'required'  => true,

    ));

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}  
}
```

The value of the 'stock field is not saved'.

I checked that the column stock exist in the db and en name's are the same.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have added stock field after all the others it is possible that you only need to clear cache through admin System -> Cache Management (Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage buttons).
Magento likes to cache previous queries so adding new fields without clearing the cache can cause problems with new columns not being saved.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didnt know that backend queries are also cached.